# CakePHP: How to get ID for a row that matches slug?

Tags: cakephp, routes, slug

I have a Model called Posts with a field called slug. I want to create a routing function to basically do this: www.mysite.com/slug. So, I created a Slug class that is used in the routes.php file, which looks like so, and it doesn't work like I want:

```
class SlugRoute extends CakeRoute {

   function match($url) 
   {
        App::import('Model', 'Post');
        $Post = new Post();
        $Post->find('first', array('conditions' => array('Post.slug' == $url)));
        $id = $Post['id'];
        return $id;
   }
}
```

Here's the line of code I have in my routes.php file:

```
Router::connect('/:slug', array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'view'), array('routeClass' => 'SlugRoute'));
```

All I want to do is perform a search on my Posts to match the input slug in the URL with what I have in my database, then return the ID and automatically link to that ID.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I found this example which does the exact same thing you're doing but uses the `parse` method instead of the `match` method. Have a look : http://mark-story.com/posts/view/using-custom-route-classes-in-cakephp

Comment: I tried that out and asked the writer why it doesn't work. Unfortunately it doesn't though, but thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$Post = new Post();
    $data = $Post->find('first', array('conditions' => array('Post.slug' => $url)));
    $id = $data['Post']['id'];
```

Comment: @shota, I tried that too. It's probably the correct syntax but it doesn't work either.

Comment: enable debug mode and you'll  see what SQL is generated. it'll help to figure out what's not right.

Comment: Do you recieve any errors? copy that SQL to your phpmyadmin an see if it returns the row you need

Comment: @shota, I tried  your new code and received the following errors:
`array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #1 is not an array [CORE\cake\dispatcher.php, line 267]`
`Undefined index: controller [CORE\cake\dispatcher.php, line 121]`
and the following "Missing Controller" error:
`Error: Controller could not be found.`

The SQL seems almost right, but there's a slash in there:
SELECT `Post`.`id`, `Post`.`slug`, `Post`.`title`, `Post`.`body`, `Post`.`created`, `Post`.`modified` FROM `posts` AS `Post` WHERE `Post`.`slug` = '/about' LIMIT 1